# Same locale, different distrib, inconsistent behavior

Tags: debian, centos, locale, glibc

I migrate a system from a CentOS 6.9 VM to a Debian 10 Docker container, and I can't explain why thousands separator differs. Same locale (fr_FR.UTF-8), same version of the locale yet different separator:

CentOS 6.9 VM:

```
[user@host ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

[user@host ~]$ locale -v -a fr_FR.UTF-8 | grep -A10 fr_FR.utf8
locale: fr_FR.utf8      archive: /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | French locale for France
   source | RAP
  contact | Traduc.org
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | French
territory | France
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2008-03-15
  codeset | UTF-8

[user@host ~]$ yum list installed | grep libc
glibc.x86_64                         2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                @updates 
glibc-common.x86_64                  2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                @updates 
glibc-devel.x86_64                   2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                @updates 
glibc-headers.x86_64                 2.12-1.209.el6_9.2                @updates
[...]

[user@host ~]$ grep "thousands_sep" /usr/share/i18n/locales/fr_FR
mon_thousands_sep         "<U0020>"
thousands_sep             "<U0020>"

[user@host ~]$ LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR" printf "%'.f\n" 1234 | hexdump -C
00000000  31 20 32 33 34 0a                                 |1 234.|
00000006
```

Debian 10 container:

```
root@240c7f7ca3a1:~# cat /etc/issue.net
Debian GNU/Linux 10

root@240c7f7ca3a1:~# locale -v -a fr_FR.UTF-8 | grep -A10 fr_FR.utf8
locale: fr_FR.utf8      archive: /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | French locale for France
   source | RAP
  contact | Traduc.org
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | French
territory | France
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2008-03-15
  codeset | UTF-8

root@240c7f7ca3a1:~# apt list --installed | grep libc    
libc-bin/stable,now 2.28-10 amd64  [installé, automatique]
libc-l10n/stable,now 2.28-10 all  [installé, automatique]
libc6/stable,now 2.28-10 amd64  [installé]
[...]

root@240c7f7ca3a1:~# grep "thousands_sep" /usr/share/i18n/locales/fr_FR
mon_thousands_sep         "<U202F>"
thousands_sep             "<U202F>"

root@240c7f7ca3a1:~# LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR" printf "%'.f\n" 1234 | hexdump -C
00000000  31 e2 80 af 32 33 34 0a                           |1...234.|
00000008
```

As you can see, in the first case I get a normal space (`<U0020>` / 20), while in the latter case I get a narrow non breakable space (`<U202F>` / e2 80 af).

I understand that the NNBSP is the legit character for french locale (according to several source including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Width_variation)), but this changes my application behavior when PDF reports are getting generated (this character does not exist in every font).

I see a lot of debates about what character it should be on GNU/Glibc/JDK mailing lists, but can't find where it's been changed in [Glibc changelog](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS;hb=HEAD).

I could simply replace all NNBSP with standard space (or simple NBSP) directly in my code to fix the application, but this seems a bit messy to me.
I guess I can modify locale file and recompile it ?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: It is [sourceware bug 20756](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20756).

Comment: I missed this entry, thank you! No I get the origin, I'd either like to fix this system wide or check which font sets have this character, do you know how I could do this?